# Macbook air 2015 trackpad short

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, trackpad, repair

I recently spilled some water on my macbook and it stopped working. I opened it up and cleaned all corrosion I found. Thankfully, it booted up but I noticed that the trackpad and keyboard were not working. The trackpad got very hot to the touch. A chip on the trackpad board was getting very hot as soon as it boots up. The chip that gets scorching hot is shown in the image below:

[image: This is the chip that gets scorching hot]

Now the reason I'm stumped is because I replaced the trackpad with a new one, and the new one gets hot in the exact same place as the old one. So I guess this is caused by some other problem other than the trackpad itself. I am very unsure what it could be though which is why I'm asking here. To make sure it wasn't caused by the keyboard I ran it with the keybard ribbon cable disconnected but the short is still there. Also I should note that when it is connected the keyboard caps lock light flickers.

In order to not do further damage I've been running it with the ribbon cable for the trackpad disconnected. I would run it like this forever if I could but I believe this causes the SMC to freak out, so now my system is very slow and has the fan on full blast constantly.